# Avoiding Circular Dependencies with socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io, ecmascript-6, circular-dependency

I am building a project with socket.io and node. Events get emitted to the socket then there is some logic that results in modifications to a database and more events emitted on the socket. I know how to implement the parts but I am really struggling trying to keep each component separate and avoid circular dependencies. I know I will need a data model that is only for handling data interactions so I can easily switch how I handle data interactions. I would like to separate the sockets from the logic as well. My issue is that with socket.io I need to declare handlers that reference logic but within that logic I need to reference the socket to emit events.

Some ideas I had:

- Inject the socket object to each call to the class with logic.
- Create a class to contain events that need to be emitted that are
  returned from calls to the logic then the socket calls them all.

These seem unnecessarily repetitive and convoluted. Is there a standard way to handle this kind of thing?

Comment: New idea: create a class for the logic that has an array of handler functions. In the socket module I can automatically initialize all of the listeners so I can make the socket module a dependency of the logic module but inject the handlers for initialization. Is this an alright solution?

Comment: Broad architectural questions like this with no specific code or detailed requirements really don't fit well on stack overflow as it's difficult to offer any sort of definitive answer in several paragraphs of text or code.  The only way I can think of to even begin here is to offer a generic tutorial on modularizing your code and sharing the socket.io instance, but that's not really how stackoverflow works well.  If your requirements were a lot more detailed (probably with code included), then people could offer actual code snippets to show you how to solve a specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

After some thinking I have arrived at what I think is a reasonable solution.  Here is an implementation of a socket module that takes an onConnection function and an array of named listener functions. It requires an express app, which is the app parameter. I use passportSocketIo to authorize. Ignore the authentication bits if you are not implementing authentication. It is a bit rough but it works. The handler can contain all of your logic.

```
import Server from 'socket.io';
import passportSocketIo from 'passport.socketio';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';

// Configured redisStore for authentication
import {redisStore} from '../lib/sessions';

// Configured passport strategy for authentication
import passport from '../lib/passport';

export default function Socket(app, port, onConnection, listeners) {
  // Setup socket
  var server = new Server();
  var io = server.listen(app.listen(port));

  // Setup authentication
  io.use(passportSocketIo.authorize({
    key: 'connect.sid',
    secret: 'censored',
    store: redisStore,
    passport: passport,
    cookieParser: cookieParser,
    success: (data, accept) => accept(null, true),
    failure: (data, message, err, accept) => {console.log(err); if(err) throw new Error(message);}
  }));

  // On connection listener
  io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    // Call the handlers method for new connections
    onConnection(socket);

    // Create listeners for all of the listeners
    listeners.forEach((listener) => {
      socket.on(listener.name, listener);
    });
  });

  return io;
}
```